# Falha na execução de loop

Tags: c++

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define     ACCOUNT_MAX    3

using namespace std;

class User 
{
private:
    struct Accounts {string user, password, firstName;};
    struct Accounts accs[ACCOUNT_MAX];
    bool online;

    void setAccounts() 
    {   
        accs[0].user = "admin";
        accs[0].password = "adminpw";
        accs[0].firstName = "Administrator";
        accs[1].user = "user01";
        accs[1].password = "user01pw";
        accs[1].firstName = "User 01";
        accs[2].user = "user02";
        accs[2].password = "user02pw";
        accs[2].firstName = "User 02";
    }

public:
    int Access(string user, string password)
    {
        int count = 0;

        for (; count <= ACCOUNT_MAX; count++)
        {
            if (user.compare(this->accs[count].user) == 0 && password.compare(this->accs[count].password) == 0)  
            {
                this->online = true;
                break;
            }

            else
                this->online = false;
        }

        return this->online;
    }

    User() {}
    ~User() {}
};

int main()
{
    class User *managment = new User();
    string localUser, localPassword;

    cout << "A system [Version 2.0]\n" << endl;

    do {
        cout << "User: ";
        cin >> localUser;
        cout << "Password: ";
        cin >> localPassword;
    } while (managment->Access(localUser, localPassword) == false);



    return 0;  
}
```

Alguém poderia me dizer porque a condição não é lida?
O programa sempre retorna 0.

Answer (score 1):

O construtor da classe User não faz nada, portanto o método setAccounts nunca é chamado...esse é o erro.

Outra coisa estranha (mas não errada) é a declaração

```
class User *managment = new User();
```

O normal seria seria simplesmente declarar

```
User managment;
```

Mais coisas estranhas: o método

```
int Access(string user, string password);
```

deveria ser declarado

```
bool Access(const string& user, const string& password);
```

A declaração de Accounts também é um pouco estranha, em C++ não é muito comum ter declarações de classes aninhadas, então a struct Accounts provavelmente ficaria melhor se declarada fora da classe User, antes da classe User. Além disso não é comum declarar instâncias de uma classe reutilizando as palavras reservadas class e struct.
Essas seriam as declarações normais:

```
Accounts accs[ACCOUNT_MAX];
User managment;
```

sem as palavras reservadas struct e class.

Ops, mais um erro:

```
for (; count <= ACCOUNT_MAX; count++)
```

deveria ser

```
for (; count < ACCOUNT_MAX; count++)
```

Agora mais uma coisa estranha:
esta linha

```
   if (user.compare(this->accs[count].user) == 0 && password.compare(this->accs[count].password) == 0)
```

normalmente seria escrita simplesmente

```
   if (user == accs[count].user && password == accs[count].password)
```

Mais uma coisa estranha: estas duas linhas

```
   int count = 0;
   for (; count <= ACCOUNT_MAX; count++)
```

normalmente seria escritas apenas como

```
   for (int count = 0; count < ACCOUNT_MAX; count++)
```

Talvez tenha mais coisas "estranhas" ainda, se procurar...

Comment: JDHSAUESA obrigado pela delicadeza em citar coisas estranhas, nunca me senti tão bem recebido lmao. De qualquer maneira, obrigado.